# How can Django not see a defined url?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've recently started learning Django for my course project, and my app works perfectly on my local machine. However, when another person clones the project from GitHub and runs it via Docker Compose, he gets an error 404 (trying to access the `form/`):

```
Using the URLconf defined in app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
api/ trText/ [name='tr_text']
The current path, api/form/, didn’t match any of these.
```

The `app/urls.py` is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('aitranslate.urls')),
]
```

The `aitranslate/urls.py` is:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import tr_text, translator

urlpatterns = [
    path('trText/', tr_text, name='tr_text'),
    path('form/', translator, name='translator'),
]
```

Why does it see `trText/` but doesn't see `form/`? And how can it work on my local machine without this problem? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you restart the server? Sometimes it does not restart with edits.

Comment: I didn't edit the code, I cloned the latest version from GitHub and it gave me this error :(

Comment: Are there `*.pyc` files in the repository? If yes, you should remove the Python caches.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, the problem was with Docker, not with the project itself. When I added the form, I didn't create a new container, I used the old version where there was no form. I'm sorry for bothering you

Answer (score 0):

I actually made a mistake, the problem was not with Django, it was with Docker. When I added the form, I didn't create a new container, I used its old version (which I created earlier to test working with Docker) where there was no form. Now I deleted the old container, created a new one, and now it works.